In Angular 15, does ng build/ npm run build exclude spec files by default?
I've read different docs already but was unable to find something that explicitly states that npm run build excludes spec files by default.
I tried inspecting the main.js file in dist folder but contents of my spec files weren't there does it necessarily mean that it was excluded during the build?

Why would they include the tests? The build process is to create the files served in production. It follows imports from the entrypoint (src/main.ts) so unless you've imported tests from implementation (which would be a bad idea) they're never reached by the bundler.

The builder typically exclude everything not imported in your ts files, this is done via treeshaking, hence it will not be includes. But typically you will also see in the tsconfig.spec.ts file it includes *.spec.ts files in there, and hence they only get build via npm run tests if you have that listed in your package.json.
So in short. No should not be included.
